# Limit of the given set

Tags: metric-spaces

$S=\{ p \: \mathrm{if} \:  n=p^r,r>1 \: \mathrm{and} \: 0  \: \mathrm{otherwise}\}$
Where $p$ is prime no. And $n$ is natural no.
$S=\{0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2......\}$
my teacher says all $p$ and $0$ are limit point of set $S$
but according to def of limit point every neighborhood of limit point must contain infinite many point of set.
so in general this set is
$S=\{0,p\}$ where $p$ is prime no. 
so $0$ has no point in is nbd, as I thinks, so how it could be limit point of set $S$
but my teacher says their is infinite many zero in set so nbd of $0$ contains infinite many point of $S$ , so it is limit point
Plz help bcz I am stuck between my thinking and my teacher bcz repeated elements in set can be taken as one

Comment: I put dollar sign to change line but don't know where is gone

Comment: I cleaned up your text with correct dollar signs and whatnot; I advise you to read a very brief tutorial on LaTeX or MathJax (as is used on MSE).

Comment: Are you sure $S$ is meant to be a set rather than a sequence?  Your definition doesn't make much sense if $S$ is supposed to be a set.

Comment: As you said sequence then a point come in mind that since given S is linked with natural no. So its a sequence so I think he must has taught about limit of sequence but not set. If I am thinking right then approve my thinking